# Зачем нужен атрибут [Conditional("DEBUG")]?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть такой код но я не могу понять зачем тут нужен я гуглил и так и не понял что делает:  **[Conditional("DEBUG")]** ,ссылка от куда я брал код https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
{
    // Убедитесь, что имя свойства соответствует реальному,
    // public, свойство instance для этого объекта.
    if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
    {
        string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

        if (ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
            throw new Exception(msg);
        else
            Debug.Fail(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Указывает компиляторам, что вызов метода или атрибут следует игнорировать, если не определен заданный символ условной компиляции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документацию по атрибуту можно найти [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

Назначение атрибута — вставлять отладочный код в программу, например, код дополнительного логгирования. Метод, помеченный таким атрибутом, может выводить окно с отладочной информацией или добавлять какие-то поля в HTTP-заголовки.

Метод будет вызываться только в том случае, если вы при сборке проекта определили макрос, который указан в параметре. В отладочной версии приложения всегда определён макрос `DEBUG`:

```
#define DEBUG
```

Поэтому в отладочной версии этот метод вызывается. В релизе макроса нет, поэтому метод будет полностью удалён из сборки вместе с теми местами, где он вызывается.

Естественно, на этом методе не должно быть построено никакой логики, он должен быть `void`.

В подавляющем большинстве случаев метод используется именно с макросом `DEBUG`, но вы можете определять свои макросы.